# What is the painting J. Paul Getty buys in 'All the Money in the World'?

Tags: historical-accuracy, all-the-money-in-the-world

In Ridley Scott's "All the Money in the World", J. Paul Getty forks a sizable chunk of money for a painting instead of paying his grandson's ransom. To me, the painting looked like Raphael's [Madonna of the Pinks](https://www.nationalgallery.org.uk/paintings/research/the-madonna-of-the-pinks) but the scenes in which it was shown were dimly lighted and I couldn't discern its details. Since such painting never belonged to the real-life Getty, putting it in the movie would be a factual inaccuracy (well, as long as we assume Scott actually intended giving the movie a brush of realism and adorned Getty's mansion with paintings possessed by him in real life. We don't have to be picky to demand that the painting acquisition and his grandson's kidnapping happened at the same time in real life, just that the painting belonged to his collection. After all, researching Getty collection wouldn't be hard for the production team: it became the Getty Museum.)

To sum up: What is the painting J. Paul Getty buys in 'All the Money in the World' and was it part of the real Getty collection?

Extra trivia: Can anyone identify other paintings in the movie and if they ever belonged to Getty? I saw a Vermeer...

Comment: Do you have a picture of it?

Comment: @Boondoggle No, it isn't in the trailers and I didn't take a photo in the theater.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The community has [changed its stance on "trivia" questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006), and the ["trivia" close reason doesn’t apply anymore](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/1006). (Links lead to the relevant [meta] posts.)

Answer (score 7):

- [image: Albrecht Dürer, Madonna with Child with Pear, 1512, next to the depiction in the film]

**'*Madonna of the Pear*' or '*Virgin and child with a pear*', by Albrecht Dürer**, painted in 1512. It is [held](https://www.khm.at/de/object/7750ca3559/) by the Kunsthistorisches Museum in Vienna (under the title '*Maria mit Kind*'), and there is no trace of it ever belonging to Getty's collection ("*acquired in 1600 by Emperor Rudolf II (?); in the Treasury 1748*").
Its "*disputed provenance*", as mentioned in the film, therefore, is a fabrication.

---

As for the other paintings:
The Getty Collection can be browsed [online](https://www.getty.edu/art/collection/), but it might not contain all of the artworks the family has obtained, as many are probably held privately.
For most artworks that are on public display current ownership can easily be obtained, though.

The filming location of All the Money in the World with the most artworks is [Hatfield House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatfield_House), in Hertfordshire, England. There is a [catalogue](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000289483) available of their inventory of paintings and sculptures, but it is inaccessible online. It would shed a whole lot of light on the artworks that get little attention in the film - which, despite my eagerness to identify, are completely trivial to the interpretation of the film.
Additionally, it demonstrates how most of those artworks we see in the background are not part of the Getty collection, but **privately owned by the current marquess of Salisbury**. Moreover, having to move so many invaluable ("*priceless*") artworks around would have been unnecessary risky and costly.

- [image: Johannes Vermeer, Girl with Flute, 1665-1670, next to the depiction in the film]

**The (disputed) Vermeer was his 'Girl with a Flute'**, 1665-1670, [donated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girl_with_a_Flute#Owners) by Joseph E. Widener  - along with the rest of his art collection - to the National Gallery of Art, Washington, D.C., in 1939, [where it still is](https://www.nga.gov/collection/art-object-page.1237.html).

- [image]

A depiction of the earthly paradise with Adam and Eve hangs in one of Getty's rooms: it's **Maerten de Vos'** '[**Garden of Eden**](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Maerten_de_Vos_-_The_Garden_of_Eden,_with_the_Fall_of_Man,_the_Creation_of_Eve,_and_the_Expulsion_from_the_Garden.jpg)' from the second half of the 16th century. It was sold in 2003 through [Sotheby](https://www.christies.com/LotFinder/lot_details.aspx?intObjectID=4684773)'s by an anonymous seller.
This was filmed in Hatfield House, and is indubitably part of their collection.

- [image: Mark Rothko, untitled]

An obvious Mark Rothko, although I wasn't able to find an exact match (the lower right corner of the dark area has a characteristic 'droop'). [This](https://www.artsy.net/artwork/mark-rothko-untitled-black-and-orange-on-red) ('Untitled (Black and Orange on Red)', 1962), [this](http://www.markrothko.org/green-and-tangerine-on-red/) ('Untitled (Green and Tangerine on Red)', mid 1950's), and [this](https://www.centrepompidou.fr/en/ressources/oeuvre/cajrkgR) ('Untitled (Black, Red over Black on Red)', 1964) are similar works. The public Getty collection doesn't list any Rothko. It was likely part of the filming location.

- [image: Portrait of Eleanora of Toledo]

This is most likely **one of the [several](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Female_portraits_by_Agnolo_Bronzino) 'Portrait of Eleanora of Toledo''s that Agnolo Bronzino painted** (+/- 1545-1560). I found only one instance of what is most likely the painting as seen in the film, but it is on a [wikigallery](http://www.wikigallery.org/wiki/painting_309861/Agnolo-Bronzino/Portrait-of-Elenor-of-Toledo%2C-bust-length) page: a commercial website seemingly using Wikipedia's public domain library to present and link through to painted copies of these artworks. It can also be a copy after one of Bronzino's portraits.

[image: An overview of the other paintings visible in All the Money in the World]

As for the works I was unable to identify (LRTB), they include a 16th/17th century painting of a reclining Venus with Cupid; a full portrait of a standing man (18th c.); a full portrait of a woman in a chair (I *think* by a 20th century female artist - I recognize it, but cannot remember the name); an English or, more likely, Dutch landscape or view on a city, reminiscent of Van Ruysdael's paintings; a (late northern medieval?) portrait of a woman; a neoclassicist or baroque mythological or biblical scene; a portrait, possibly by Rembrandt; a landscape with what appears to be a bridge or a fallen tree; a portrait of a woman, possibly Judith (Peter Lely, Willem Wissing?); and another landscape.
Now I need to get my hands on one of those catalogues..

Comment: FYI, I've voted to reopen the closed question you answered here, in line with the community consensus at [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006). If you agree, then please vote to reopen it: https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/96102

Answer (score 1):

Madonna of the Pear.

#### Picture from *All the money in the world*

[image: all the money in the world, 2017]

#### Picture from [wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Durer_Mary_and_child_dsc01706.jpg)

[image: wikimedia]

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't really adress the heart of the question if that painting was actually part of Getty's collection.

Comment: You are still missing if the painting belonged to him.